# Alkane free radical halogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I do not understand how we obtain the product in option one. 
According to Free radical stability order tertiary carbon radical is more stable than secondary carbon radical which is more stable than primary carbon radical. So hydrogen selectivity should also follow the same order. Then why is it that we get option(1) instead of option (2). 
I’m only in high school so please try to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

This question is based on relative rates of reaction of different $\ce{H}$ with halogens. In the free radical mechanism of chlorination of alkane, relative rate of reaction of $\ce{3^\circ : 2^\circ : 1^\circ}$ $\ce{H}$ is in order $5:3.8: 1$.

Using this, we get an idea about product amount. To get a rough estimate of relative amounts of different products, we multiply *number of identical hydrogen and its rate of reaction with chlorine*.

So there is only $1$ $3^\circ$ $\ce{H}$ and its rel. rate is $5$. So relative amount is $5$. For the $2^\circ$ $\ce{H}$, there are $2$ of them and their relative rate is $3.8$. So its relative amount is $2 \cdot 3.8 = 7.6$. Similar calculation for rest of the hydrogens will show you why given answer is correct.

Refer: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-radical_halogenation#Control_of_halogenation)

Comment: Them number of primary hydrogens is 9. So the relative amount should be 9*1=9. Then percentage of primary chlorine should be (9/21.5)*100= 41%. Percentage of secondary chlorine should be (7.5/21.6)*100= 35%. Then shouldn’t primary monosubstitued chlorine be the major compound?

Comment: Raheeel No here s a catch. There are two types of one degree  hydrogen present.

Comment: So I shouldn’t consider primary hydrogen on substituent carbon ie side chain. Am I right?

Comment: I am saying products 3 and 4 are not identical as hydrogen's replaced by chlorine in them are not identical

Comment: You take into account 3 and 4 as different product. Then find relative amount

Comment: Ok. So that means treat it as a completely different product. Which means product 4 will have a percentage of (3/21.6)*100= 13.8%. Am I right?

Comment: Rachel yes treat as completely different product. Btw product 3 will have that percent! Product 4 will have 6/21.6 of tot. fraction

Comment: Oh yes. Product 3. My bad. Thank you very much for clearing that up.